# Feature "remove and sort usings on save" from Productivity Power Tools doesn't work in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, productivity-power-tools

Does anyone have problem with a feature "remove and sort usings on save" from Productivity Power Tools in Visual Studio 2017. It seems it doesn't work. Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: It works for me.  I've got 2017 Professional, with the update released on 14th March.  And installed Productivity Power Tools earlier.  It sorts the usings alphabetically however, which I do not like.  I want System first followed by my namespaces and 3rd party ones.  Are you using a .editorconfig file? See here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17658

Comment: @Andez I'll check this. However if you check Options>Text Editor>C#>Advanced>Place 'System' directives first when sorting usings - then System usings will be first and then Alphabetic at least in VS2015 ;)

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, that's the option I couldn't find thanks.  When I save a file the usings are all sorted.  Check your options under Options->Productivity Power Tools->PowerCommands->Commands and there are a set of checkboxes to enable Remove and Sort Usings.  For me, when I Ctrl+S in a file, this is when it applies the sorting.  There is also a Reset Productivity Power Tools in the Tools menu which might be a last resort.

Comment: For me it doesn't work either... Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I have disabled a couple of PPT plugins though, maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with PowerCommands and ReSharper.

> Please could you try unticking that checkbox "ReSharper | Options |
>   Environment | Keyboard & Menus | Hide overridden VS menu items" and
>   then check "Remove and Sort Usings on Save" feature once again.

From https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000159930/comments/115000202364

Comment: This did the trick, but after a few weeks, it randomly stopped working again. I *enabled* the R# ""Hide overridden VS menu items" setting, saved, then disabled it again and saved again, and after that remove and sort started working again.

Answer (score 23):

There is another solution [image]

Go to tool -->Option-->Text Editor--> tick/untick Remove Unncessary Using

Comment: Except this is not removing them when saving, only when formatting.

Comment: I unconsciously hit `Ctrl + K + D` after editing the code. :P

Comment: Looks like this didnt make it in to VS 2019?!

Comment: @Ernie, It's been moved around a few times in 2019, Currently look for a broom at the bottom of your text editor window. You can create different profiles with different settings, not yet found out how to swap the shortcut keys back to CTRL+ K, CTRL+D though :(

Comment: I am on VS 2017 version 15.7.5 and I don't see the entire "Format Document Settings (Experiment)" section.

Answer (score 11):

**** For Visual studio 2019 (My version is Version 16.6.3): Productivity Power Tools didnt work and the experimental flag posted on @makdo's answer isn't available.

Credit to [@mattferderer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1824367/mattferderer) for this post
https://mattferderer.com/clean-up-sort-unused-dotnet-using-statements-in-visual-studio

**How to get it working - V2019**

In the menu go to Analyze > Code Cleanup > Configure Code Cleanup. Add the following to your fixers
[image]

Once you've configured code cleanup, you need to run it. Here are your options:

- The first profile you've setup you can run with Ctrl+K, Ctrl+E.
- On the bottom (leftish) of your screen there is a tiny broom icon. Click that.
  In the menu go to Analyze > Code Cleanup. Then select the cleanup profile you want to run.
- You can run code cleanup on save with [Mads Kristensen's extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CodeCleanupOnSave)

Comment: This worked for me and didn't interfere or conflict with any Resharper settings. In addition "Run Code Cleanup profile on Save" is now a built-in option (VS 17.4.0) so the suggested extension was not required.

Comment: What is really annoying is that these settings are triggered by git merge conflict resolution in such a way as to always remove all "using" statements ... so after resolving a merge conflict, the resulting source file simply never has any using statements, causing all sorts of chaos.

Answer (score 7):

**** UPDATE: The Productivity Power Tools are no longer necessary as this feature is now part of Visual Studio 2017.  See [makdu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107577/3063884). ****

I couldn't get the "Format Document on Save" or the "Sort and Remove Usings on save" features to work on 4 different laptops no matter which version of Visual Studio 2017 I had installed (Community/Pro/Enterprise).   I think the issue is that I used the main **Productivity Power Tools 2017** extension that installs all the extensions and perhaps this extension has a bug in it?

To fix the problem and get the features working:

- Uninstalled the **Productivity Power Tools 2017** extension. (This will leave all the sub-component extensions still installed.)
- Uninstalled the individual **Power Commands for Visual Studio** extension.
- Restarted Visual Studio.
- Reinstalled the individual **Power Commands for Visual Studio** extension by itself.

Now the "Format Document on Save" and "Sort and Remove Usings on save" features work.

Comment: Same for me! Thank tou